# Protocols, standards or languages that are lacking of implementation

Tags: protocols, libraries, standards

Is there some protocol, standard or language, like YAML, GeoJSON, server-sent events, that doesn't have an library implementing it in some language like C, Python or Rust?

Looking for ideas for some library project.

I tried to use search engines but didn't manage to find any answers.